# Accessing Over the Network without sharing

Tags: c#, mysql, database, networking, connection-string

Is it possible to access a file over the **network** without sharing the folder?
I want to access my connection string over the network, I have sample shared file and it works fine but how to access my `Settings.config` without sharing the folder?

```
//sample shared file
string location = @"\\SERVER\Shared\Ramgy\Settings.config"
```

Comment: you can provide http or ftp access to file instead of smb, but in any case you will have to "share" file somehow

Comment: @IlyaBursov so there's no way to connect without sharing the folder sir

Comment: no, it will be huge security hole otherwise

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a windows machine, there is a default share for each drive (e.g. D: can be accessed using D$)

You can try accessing from Run window using `\\SERVER\D$\Ramgy\Settings.config`

Comment: @RamgyBorja `D$` is automatically shared folder, depending on multiple factors this feature either enabled or disabled

Comment: Yes, unless it is disabled by Administrator. You need to give the correct path `\\SERVER\Drive$\PathToFolder\FileName`

Comment: @Mani I tried but its not working `\\SERVER\D$\Ramgy\Setting.config`

Comment: Yes, it works without sharing. Each drive has default share, no need to explicitly share.